# Installing xampp on ubuntu

Tags: command-line

I am trying to install xampp 1.8.2-1-installer.run on a 32bit Ubuntu OS.
When I type from root

```
sudo tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.8.2.tar.gz -C /opt
tar (child): xampp-linux-1.8.2.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: child returned status 2
tar: Error  is not recoverable: exiting now
```

This is what I get when type ls

```
xampp-linux-x64-1.8.2.-1-intaller(1).run
xampp-linux-x64-1.8.2.-1-intaller(1).run~
xampp-linux-x64-1.8.2.-1-intaller(1).run.part
xampp-linux-x64-1.8.2.-1-intaller(1).run
```

Comment: Please use the native LAMP stack. It is easier to install, has better security and is tailor made for Ubuntu. (`sudo apt-get install tasksel` and `tasksel` on command line to start it. Choose LAMP and after a few seconds it is installed and ready to be used).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't finished downloading XAMPP. Are you sure you have the correct file (`xampp-linux-1.8.2.tar.gz`) for your command? Also, make sure you include a dash before xfvz, so that it reads `sudo tar -xfvz xampp-linux-1.8.2.tar.gz -C /opt`.